# Using Git to Manage a Shared Project? Using Folders (not groups) in Project?

Tags: xcode4

Was looking for a bit of Light on a few questions we have on xCode 4.  Up until now My team and I have been working on our Own projects on our own Drives. Though we are close to integrating our projects and wanted to know which Source Control we should be using to manage our Project. With xCode 4 it seems that Git is Preferred. I setup a repository on GitHub though I don't think its really what we are looking for as It does not seem that xCode knows if files from gitHub are checked in/out, only if they have changed from the last push/pull.

When Pushing my Project to GitHub I don't know why I was surprised that the Groups I created xCode didn't get converted to Folders in the Repository, but I was...  In trying to put all of the code files in folders that were represented by my groups I'm running into all my includes not being found as they are in subfolders.   Should I just not worry about it and put everything in groups and let xcode put 600 some odd files in the one Project folder, or is there a better way to manage the individual files and references to them?

Thanks!